# Where should I use release() method in android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make little application... I have used different sounds in application.. I am confused that where I should use method `release()`  to release the resources.

Can you have look at my code and let me know if I am going in the right direction:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SpellToNumbers extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btn_next;
    Button btn_restart;
    Button btn_previous;
    TextView tvSTN, tvSTNN;
    int a = 0;
    RelativeLayout stnXML;

    MediaPlayer vone,vtwo,vthree,vfour,vfive,vsix,vseven,veight,vnine,vten;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spell_to_numbers);


        MediaPlayer onStart = MediaPlayer.create(SpellToNumbers.this,  R.raw.one110 );
        onStart.start();


    tvSTN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSTN);
    tvSTNN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSTNN);
    stnXML = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.stnXML);
    btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNextSTN);
    btn_next.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_restart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRestartSTN);
    btn_restart.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPreviousSTN);
    btn_previous.setOnClickListener(this);


    vone   = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.one110); 
    vtwo   = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.two210);
    vthree = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.three310);
    vfour  = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.four410);
    vfive  = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.five510);
    vsix   = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.six610);
    vseven = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.seven710);
    veight = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.eight810);
    vnine  = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.nine910);
    vten   = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ten1010);

    }//onCreate ends




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }//onCreateOptionMenu ends



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnRestartSTN:
            restart();

            break;

        case R.id.btnNextSTN:
            next();

            break;

        case R.id.btnPreviousSTN:

            previous();

            break;
        }//switch ends

    }//onClick ends




    private void restart() {
        a = 0;
        setPage();
    }

    private void previous() {
        if (a > 0) {
            a--;
        }
        setPage();
    }

    private void next() {
        if (a < 9) {
            a++;
        }
        setPage();
    }




            private void setPage() {
                    if (a == 0) {
                        tvSTNN.setText("1");
                        tvSTN.setText("ONE");
                        tvSTNN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F2416B"));
                        tvSTN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F2416B"));
                        stnXML.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3FD161"));
                        vone.start();
                        }
                    if (a == 1)
                        {
                        tvSTNN.setText("2");
                        tvSTNN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F0EFDA"));
                        tvSTN.setText("TWO");
                        tvSTN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F0EFDA"));
                        stnXML.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0A0EF5"));
                        vtwo.start();
                         }

                    else if (a == 2)
                        {                       
                        tvSTNN.setText("3");
                        tvSTNN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F507"));
                        tvSTN.setText("THREE");
                        tvSTN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F507"));
                        stnXML.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D15BE3"));
                        vthree.start();
                        }

                    else if (a == 3)
                        {                       
                        tvSTNN.setText("4");
                        tvSTNN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0AF5DD"));
                        tvSTN.setText("FOUR");
                        tvSTN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0AF5DD"));
                        stnXML.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F50A0A"));
                        vfour.start();
                        }

                    else if (a == 4)
                        {                       
                        tvSTNN.setText("5");
                        tvSTNN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#171117"));
                        tvSTN.setText("FIVE");
                        tvSTN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#171117"));
                        stnXML.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0AF5DD"));
                        vfive.start();
                        }

                    else if (a == 5)
                        {                       
                        tvSTNN.setText("6");
                        tvSTNN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#072BF5"));
                        tvSTN.setText("SIX");
                        tvSTN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#072BF5"));
                        stnXML.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0AF525"));
                        vsix.start();
                        }

                    else if (a == 6)
                        {                       
                        tvSTNN.setText("7");
                        tvSTNN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8F0AF5"));
                        tvSTN.setText("SEVEN");
                        tvSTN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8F0AF5"));
                        stnXML.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F10A"));
                        vseven.start();
                        }

                    else if (a == 7)
                        {                       
                        tvSTNN.setText("8");
                        tvSTNN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#37F507"));
                        tvSTN.setText("EIGHT");
                        tvSTN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#37F507"));
                        stnXML.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9C2497"));
                        veight.start();
                        }

                    else if (a == 8)
                        {                       
                        tvSTNN.setText("9");
                        tvSTNN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F50707"));
                        tvSTN.setText("NINE");
                        tvSTN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F50707"));
                        stnXML.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BAF50A"));
                        vnine.start();
                        }

                    else if (a == 9)
                        {
                        tvSTNN.setText("10");
                        tvSTNN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0ACAF5"));
                        tvSTN.setText("TEN");
                        tvSTN.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0ACAF5"));
                        stnXML.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5700A"));
                        vten.start();
                        tvSTN.setClickable(false);
                        }

        }//setPage Method ends

}//end of class
```

Comment: Thanks Tshepang for editing...Actually English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking your code I think it is better to use ***soundpool instead of Mediaplayer***.

Any way you can release your resources from mediaplayer when your application is going to backgound(onPause()) and on onResume() you can re-assign resources to mediaplayer.

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
     onStart.release();
     super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
     vone   = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.one110); 
     vtwo   = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.two210);
     vthree = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.three310);
     vfour  = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.four410);
     vfive  = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.five510);
     vsix   = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.six610);
     vseven = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.seven710);
     veight = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.eight810);
     vnine  = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.nine910);
     vten   = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ten1010);
     super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: ok...and if i click on next button or previous button continuously means without any pause so can be affected playing sounds?

Comment: and please tell me that when and who will invoke onPause()...?

Comment: Sorry i mean onResume() not onPause()

Comment: When your activity comes to foreground onResume() will be called

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused that where i should use method release();

If you are only using the `MediaPlayer` to play one song, one time then you should put that in `onPause()`

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
     onStart.release();
     super.onPause();
}
```

this will release the resources if another `Activity` comes into the foreground or if the `Activity` is destroyed. If you were using it in different places in the `Activity` then you would want to release the resources each time it was done before calling `start()` on it again.

Answer (score 0):

On onResume()method starts the media player if creation is successful

The onPause() method pauses the MediaPlayer. If the activity is going to be killed, stop the
MediaPlayer and then release all of its resources.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
   if (mediaPlayer != null) {
     mediaPlayer.start();
   }
}

protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
   if (mediaPlayer != null) {
     mediaPlayer.pause();
  if (isFinishing()) {
     mediaPlayer.stop();
     mediaPlayer.release();
   }
}
```